# Error while generating video thumbnail in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, video-thumbnails, ffmpeg-php

I am using ffmpeg and [Pawlox/video-thumbnail](https://github.com/pawlox/video-thumbnail) package to generate thumbnail. I have already installed both ffmpeg and pawlox/video-thumbnail.

Here is my code.

```
VideoThumbnail::createThumbnail(url('/storage/app/accident_report_videos/ynvO5D9GzUJsLPj8vPlyiOEND0ag9MeFGr4NFu5k.mp4'), asset('thumbnAils'), '111.jpg', 2, 600, 600);
```

Error:

```
error:getimagesize(http://54.255.240.102/storage/app/accident_report_videos/thumbs/ynvO5D9GzUJsLPj8vPlyiOEND0ag9MeFGr4NFu5k.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Video path and thumbnail path are both right. But it is using thumbnail method in [videothumbnail.php](https://github.com/pawlox/video-thumbnail/blob/master/src/VideoThumbnail.php) to create thumbnail. This function is generating thumbnail. So after that it calls `resizeCropImage()` function in which they uses `getimagesize()` funtion. And `getiamgesize()` function does not get image from because it is never generated.

Comment: Did you configure the `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` binaries paths?

Comment: i just run command from official documentation. Please guide me how to configure binaries path

Comment: i run whereis ffmpeg command on server and it gives me path \usr\bin\ffmpeg

Comment: 1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media  
2. sudo apt-get update  
3. sudo apt-get install ffmpeg  
4 .sudo apt-get install frei0r-plugins

Comment: Did you `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=video-thumbnail`?

Comment: yes i did run this command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use `url()` here - it's going to generate a full HTTP URL, which means your server's going to have to *download* the full MP4 file (which could be gigabytes!) to screenshot it.

(Your storage directory is also typically *not available* via HTTP...)

Use an actual path, via the `storage_path()` helper.

```
VideoThumbnail::createThumbnail(storage_path('app/accident_report_videos/ynvO5D9GzUJsLPj8vPlyiOEND0ag9MeFGr4NFu5k.mp4'), storage_path('app/accident_report_videos/thumbs'), '111.jpg', 2, 600, 600);
```